# Cannot compile Win32 application in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, winapi

It's my first time playing around with the Win32 API. What I'm trying to do is to make a simple window. I'm writing the code in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 with all the required things installed to work with C++. The problem I'm having is that none of the code I found from searching around the web has worked, even just the simple `wWinMain`. Is there something I am doing completely wrong? or is there something special with VS2019 or Windows 10 in general?

I tried running the code from a bunch of different sources. 
Also tried manually running the code with the `cl` compiler from the terminal.

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    /* Some Code*/
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

```
Warning C28251 Inconsistent annotation for 'wWinMain': this instance has no annotations.
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)  
Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your application from "Console" to "Windows"
Right click on project -> Properties -> Linker options -> System.

[image]